# Binding value to ComboBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

So, I need to make a WPF app that'll take values from the list and store them to DataGrid. I have 3 fields I want to show in the grid: Username, FullName and Role. Now, the Role can have 2 values: shopper and supplier. How do I make that part of the DataGridTemplate? In addition, how do I select the right one on load for every user? The empty line is where the missing code should be. Here's the code I'm working on:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding UserList}" Name="dgUsers" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="450" Width="400">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Username" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Username}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Full Name" Width="200" IsReadOnly="True">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FullName}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Role" Width="100">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

**EDIT:**

As a DataTemplate I did this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding valueList}" SelectedIndex="{Binding Role}"/>
     </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

As a Role, inside of the constructor, I did this:

```
public class UserToChange
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public int Role { get; set; }
    public List<string> valueList { get; set; }

    public UserToChange()
    {

    }

    public UserToChange(UserVM row)
    {
        Username = row.UserName;
        FullName = row.FirstName + " " + row.LastName;
        Role = row.RoleId == 102 ? 0 : 1;
        valueList = new List<string>
        {
            "Supplier",
            "Shopper"
        };
    }
}
```

And it worked. Now I need to program the logic to update Database, but I can handle that. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First Fill the ListofRole collection with your respective values.
2. Bind it with the combo-box inside DataGridTemplateColumn.
3. Bind the SelectedValue property of combo-box, and there comes to magic, bind SelectedValue to that variable which contains a Role value in a dataList.

   Note: ListofRole collection should not be an of custom type, then we need to add some more parameters in combo box, it should be a normal string type.

   ```
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Role" Width="0.45*">
                   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                           <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfRole}" 
                                     SelectedValue="{Binding Role,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                       </DataTemplate>
                   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   ```

Comment: I actually did something different. :D Answer is in edited part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the Collection in two ways.

1) Create a `ComboBox` inside `DataTemplate`

```
         <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Role" Width="100">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding dataList}"  Width="100" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding DisplayProperty}" SelectedValuePath="{Binding PropertyId}" SelectedIndex="0" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

For ComboBox, Use SelectedIndex to set a default Item on Load.

2) Instead of `DataGridTemplateColumn`  use `DataGridComboBoxColumn`

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn ItemsSource="{Binding dataList}" Width="100" Header="Role2" DisplayMemberPath="{Binding DisplayProperty}" SelectedValuePath="{Binding PropertyId}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding DefaultValuePro, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

For DataGridComboBoxColumn use SelectedItemBinding bind it with property to set a default value.

Comment: I tried to do that, but nothing happened. It does not load anything into the data grid.

Comment: @Alex 1) Does the Datagrid has Records ? 
2) Have you bidden with any List to ComboBox ?